# Extract zip file and overwrite (in the same directory - C#)

Tags: c#, zip, extract, updates, archive

I'm starting some C# stuff, and i would like to extract and force to overwrite all files from a zip archive. I know that there are many other solution in Stack, but nothing works for me :/

i've tried this method:

```
try
{
   string zipPath = (Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + "my_zip");
   Console.WriteLine("Zip's path: " + zipPath);
   string extractPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

   ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
   return (0); // 0 all fine 
}
catch (Exception)
{
   return (1); // 1 = extract error
}
```

This extractor works fine, but doesn't allow me to overwrite files meanwhile extraction, and it returns error and exceptions ... i've tried to take a look at [MS-Documention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zipfileextensions.extracttofile?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Compression_ZipFileExtensions_ExtractToFile_System_IO_Compression_ZipArchiveEntry_System_String_System_Boolean_), without success ...

someone know how does it work ?

Comment: You cannot write to a file/folder if it is open or somebody else owns the file/folder.  The is an issue with Windows and just happens to apply to the unzip method.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for the reply! I'm trying to extract-overwrite only closed file opened by no one !

Comment: If the new and old files are identical then how do you know if they are overwritten?

Comment: @jdweng How can they bee identical? let's follow my example: i have a folder, in which we have a text file called "random.txt" and we also have an "update.zip" archive, which contain another "random.txt". The contents of these two file "random.txt" are different, even if the name is the same. I need to extract the which is on the zip archive, and replace the which one that is out of the archive

Comment: A zip file when you update an existing zip it adds the new file and keeps the old file.  But when you unzip is only unzips the last file added.  Files were newer versions were not added will be identical.  Then other times you only archive files to zip file that changed size the last archive.  It is not clear exactly what you are trying to do.  Also not clear why you are getting the exception.  The only reason for an exception is if the file is corrupted or if you cannot write the file because (usually due to somebody else owning the file)

Comment: @jdweng i would like create an update system, where i would like take the new version of the files, by zip archive , and directly extract that into the main folder. The exception is this one: Error!System.IO.IOException: The file `'D:\Informatica\Zip_excract\ZipExtractor\ZipExtractor\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\extract\random.txt' already exists` That's exception occurred because there is already a file called "random.txt" out of the archive, and the process can not overwrite it :/

Comment: Did you set the overwrite parameter to TRUE like you link says?

Comment: @jdweng, nope, i didn't, because in to the MS documention i found the "ExtractToFile" Method and not the "ExtractToDirectory" that is which one i'm using !!

Comment: You are correct. The Extract ToDicrectory there is no way to override the existing file exception.  So you have to use the ExtractToFile method with the overwrite parameter set to true.

Comment: Got it ! Thank you i will give a try!

Comment: You can always use another tool.  ZIP is a standard specification.  The issue is there are different versions of the specification and optional requirements.  So not all tools work with all zip files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this. Away from my dev box so this may require some tweaking, just writing it from memory.

Edit: As someone mentioned you can use ExtractToFile which has an overwrite option. ExtractToDirectory does not.

Essentially you unzip to a temporary folder then check if an unzipped file's name already exists in the destination folder. If so, it deletes the existing file and moves the newly unzipped one to the destination folder.

```
    try
    {
        string zipPath = (Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + "my_zip");
        Console.WriteLine("Zip's path: " + zipPath);
        //Declare a temporary path to unzip your files
        string tempPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "tempUnzip");
        string extractPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, tempPath);

        //build an array of the unzipped files
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(tempPath);

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(file);
            //Check if the file exists already, if so delete it and then move the new file to the extract folder
            if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(extractPath,f.Name)))
            {
                File.Delete(Path.Combine(extractPath, f.Name));
                File.Move(f.FullName, Path.Combine(extractPath, f.Name));
            }
            else
            {
                File.Move(f.FullName, Path.Combine(extractPath, f.Name));
            }
        }
        //Delete the temporary directory.
        Directory.Delete(tempPath);
        return (0); // 0 all fine 
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return (1); // 1 = extract error
    }
```

Edit, in the event directories are unzipped (again, may need to be tweaked, I didn't test it):

```
        try
        {
            string zipPath = (Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + "my_zip");
            Console.WriteLine("Zip's path: " + zipPath);
            //Declare a temporary path to unzip your files
            string tempPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "tempUnzip");
            string extractPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, tempPath);

            //build an array of the unzipped directories:
            string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(tempPath);

            foreach (string folder in folders)
            {
                DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
                //If the directory doesn't already exist in the destination folder, move it to the destination.
                if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(extractPath,d.Name)))
                {
                    Directory.Move(d.FullName, Path.Combine(extractPath, d.Name));
                    continue;
                }
                //If directory does exist, iterate through the files updating duplicates.
                else
                {
                    string[] subFiles = Directory.GetFiles(d.FullName);
                    foreach (string subFile in subFiles)
                    {
                        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(subFile);
                        //Check if the file exists already, if so delete it and then move the new file to the extract folder
                        if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(extractPath, d.Name, f.Name)))
                        {
                            File.Delete(Path.Combine(extractPath, d.Name, f.Name));
                            File.Move(f.FullName, Path.Combine(extractPath, d.Name, f.Name));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            File.Move(f.FullName, Path.Combine(extractPath, d.Name, f.Name));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            //build an array of the unzipped files in the parent directory
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(tempPath);

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                FileInfo f = new FileInfo(file);
                //Check if the file exists already, if so delete it and then move the new file to the extract folder
                if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(extractPath,f.Name)))
                {
                    File.Delete(Path.Combine(extractPath, f.Name));
                    File.Move(f.FullName, Path.Combine(extractPath, f.Name));
                }
                else
                {
                    File.Move(f.FullName, Path.Combine(extractPath, f.Name));
                }
            }
            Directory.Delete(tempPath);
            return (0); // 0 all fine 
        }
```

Comment: Amazing ... wow ... really nice reply bro! It works! Now i just need to figure out how to remove the zip once extracted! Really helpful !

Comment: No that hard, just a simple " File.Delete(file_name);" is enought!

Comment: Your works looks good, but seems to have problem whit folders: if i try to extract a folder and then replace it, it doens't work!

Comment: @Zenek Are you wanting to replace a folder with all of it's contents? That's a different question entirely if so.

Comment: you have absolutely right. Probably my question wasn't correctly post. I mean, i need to extract and replace every type of file in the directory even if they are in a sub folder!

Comment: subfolder conditions added.

Comment: Thank you for the amazing work that your are doing, i'm learning a lot! The code works really good, but has some problem with the deletion of file: when you extract a sub-folder, is now correctly replaced, but at the end doesn't remove the "zip" files (where update come from) and "tmp" folder. The program return this exception : Exception thrown: `'System.IO.IOException' in mscorlib.dll`